# Finding the "Larger" of Two Cosine Values

Tags: trigonometry

The question is as follows:

> Without using a calculator, choose the larger of $\cos 310^\circ$ and $\cos 311^\circ$. Explain.

I am having difficulty understand the meaning of the word "larger" in this context. Does it possibly mean a value that is $\cos310^\circ < \cos\theta < \cos311^\circ$? If so, then would be a possible number be $\cos310.5^\circ$? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are being asked whether $\cos 310 \gt \cos 311$, or $\cos 310 \lt \cos 311$.

Comment: 310 degree or radians?

Comment: May we safely assume that your angles are measured in degrees?

Comment: @user8734617, you can assume that it is in degrees.

Comment: Just edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you @user8734617!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that in the fourth quadrant, that is for $270°\le \theta \le360°$, $\cos \theta$ is increasing up to 1.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I realize how idiotic I sounded when I asked the question about which value is larger. The way the question was phrased tripped me.

Comment: @geo_freak You are welcome, no question is idiotic! For trigonometric issue keep always in mind he geometric definition, it is very important also for more challenging problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas,

$$\cos310-\cos311=2\sin(0.5)\sin(300.5)$$

Now $$\sin(300.5)=\sin(360-59.5)=-\sin59.5<0$$